# How to save XGBoost/LightGBM model to PostgreSQL database in Python for subsequent inference in Java?

Tags: python, java, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

I'm restricted to a `PostgreSQL` as 'model storage' for the models itself or respective components (coefficients, ..). Obviously, `PostgreSQL` is far from being a fully-fledged model storage, so I can't rule out that I have to implement the whole model training process in `Java` [...].

I couldn't find a solution that involves a `PostgreSQL` database as intermediate storage for the models. Writing files directly to the disk/other storages isn't really an option for me. I considered calling `Python` code from within the `Java` application but I don't know whether this would be an efficient solution for subsequent inference tasks and beyond [...]. Are there ways to serialize `PMML` or other formats that can be loaded via `Java` implementations of the algorithms? Or ways to use the model definitions/parameters directly for reproducing the model [...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I found out is to save the `LightGBM` model to `str` in `Python`, to subsequentially [store](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.model_to_string) it in a respective `postgres` column (`character varying`):

```
booster_.model_to_string(num_iteration=best_iteration_)
```

In Java you can use the [`LightGBM4j`](https://github.com/metarank/lightgbm4j), an (inofficial) `Java`-wrapper for `LightGBM` to load the model with the previouly stored model string:

```
LGBMBooster booster = LGBMBooster.loadModelFromString(modelString);
```

One problem seems to arise when using cateogrial variables (of type 'category' in Python), since this `Java` wrapper seems to only support matrices in `double` or `float` [...].

With [`dmlc xgboost`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) there seems to exist a more 'final' version of a `Java`-wrapper for XGBoost, so maybe switching from LightGBM to [`XGBoost`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may offer a more stable version with some extended functionalities in comparison (at least by the time of writing).

Comment: Your setup leads to the "explosion" of model formats on the database side. Looks like you need one column for LightGBM models (text string), another for XGBoost models (JSON string or UBJSON blob), and a third one for pure Python models (Pickle blob). If you simply dumped in Pickle data format, then you could perform this Pickle-to-X data format conversion anytime in the future.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my approach. Theoretically, I only need one column for the model_string(s) for LightGBM. I don't want to use both at once - XGBoost and LightGBM. Also I don't need to load a previously trained model into Python again, since inference will always be made in the Java application and training is performed in a stateless way periodically. Although, with the new option of dmlc xgboost, the possibility of completly switching to Java for inference *and* training comes into mind.

Answer (score 0):

Using PostgreSQL as dummy model storage:

1. Train a model in Python.
2. Establish PostgreSQL connection, dump your model in Pickle data format to the "models" table. Obviously, the data type of the main column should be BLOB.
3. Anytime you want to use the model for some application, unpickle it from the "models" table.

The "models" table may have extra columns for storing the model in alternative data formats such as PMML. Assuming you've used correct Python-to-PMML conversion tools, you can assume that the Pickle representation and the PMML representation of the same model will be functionally identical (ie. making the same prediction when given the same input). Using PMML in Java/JVM applications is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think one problem is, that a serialized python object can't be 'used' in Java since its naturally only syntactically valid in Python. Furthermore, I am only aware of conversion methods model-to-PMML in a way that directly writes a file to disk, so I would need to take a detour in order to save it into a database. Are you aware of a methods that lets me dump the PMML directly to the respective database column?

Comment: Can't you write the PMML into a temporary file initially? PostgreSQL should even support SQL syntax for loading file contents into a table column automatically. If temporary files are strictly verboten, then you'd need to ask model-to-PMML converter maintainers to provide a "streaming" conversion endpoint (eg. raw stream, HDFS or AWS URL etc).